# Help with a problem regarding sequence divergence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

There are two forms of definition of sequence divergence.

By negation of the sequence convergence we have

> A sequence $x_k$ diverges iff $∀x∈\Bbb{R}∃ϵ>0∀N∈\Bbb{N}∃k>N$ st. $|x_k-x|>ϵ$.

By negation of Cauchy criterion we have

> A sequence $x_k$ diverges iff $∃ϵ>0∀N∈\Bbb{N}∃m,n>N$ st. $m≠n$ implies $|x_m-x_n |>ϵ$.

Now I want to **prove a third equivalent form**.

> A sequence $x_k$ diverges iff $∃ϵ>0∀N∈\Bbb{N}∃m>N$ st. $|x_m-x_N |>ϵ$.

I have difficulty with this proof. I have tried trigonometric inequality but with no success. For example, suppose the third definition holds, then given $N_1<N_2$ we have $\forall x$ $\exists m_1>N_1,\exists m_2>N_2$ st. $|x_{m_1}-x |>\frac{ϵ}{2}$, $|x_{m_2}-x |>\frac{ϵ}{2}$, but this simply gets stuck because $|x_{m_1}-x |+|x_{m_2}-x |>|x_{m_1}-x_{m_2}|$ and so I cannot say $|x_{m_1}-x_{m_2}|>\epsilon$.

Can anyone offer some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every subsequence of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy.

The condition mentioned in the third form implies the existence of an $\epsilon>0$ together with a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ that satisfies $|x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}|>\epsilon$ for each $k$.

Just start with some $n_1$ and find an index $n_2>n_1$ with $|x_{n_{2}}-x_{n_1}|>\epsilon$ and repeat this proces.

Then the subsequence is not Cauchy hence the original sequence is not Cauchy.